# Mysql query when using INTERVAL

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I am just trying to add 330 minutes to current time but when I use DATE_ADD function it gives me an error:

The error it gives me is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' INTERVAL 330 MINUTE), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"),c.start_time) as time_remaining F' at line 1

The error i get is in this section:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 330 MINUTE)
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  c.id as call_id,
  c.expert_id,
  c.user_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(c.start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") as start_time,
  u.username as user_name,
  u.email as user_email,
  e.username as expert_name,
  e.email as expert_email,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 330 MINUTE),
      "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"
    ),
    c.start_time
  ) as time_remaining
FROM
  `call` c
  JOIN `user` u ON u.id = c.`user_id`
  JOIN `expert` e ON e.id = c.`expert_id`
WHERE
  c.`status` = "schedule"
  AND c.`sent_call_reminder` = 0
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 330 MINUTE),
      "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"
    ),
    c.start_time
  ) > 25
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    MINUTE,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 330 MINUTE),
      "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00"
    ),
    c.start_time
  ) < 35
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your timestampdiff, i tried it on sqlfiddle and it works just fine. Please try to make an sqlfiddlw or dbfiddlr example, because i can't see an error in your syntax.

Comment: @Max Voisard  it is not right. DATE_ADD admits just DATE or DATETIME

Comment: @nacho I know, that's why I deleted my comment. But to @D555, it could be a syntax issue reading the format of `c.start_time`, although it looks like it's in the right format from years down to seconds

Comment: Sure, I will check